# Declaring lifetime on a test function

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have a test in progress that does not compile:

```
#[test]
fn node_cost_dequeue() {
    let mut queue: BinaryHeap<&NodeCost> = BinaryHeap::new();
    let cost_1: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(1, 50, 0);
    let cost_2: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(2, 30, 0);
    let cost_3: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(3, 80, 0);
    queue.push(&cost_1);
    queue.push(&cost_2);
    queue.push(&cost_3);
    assert_eq!(2, (*queue.pop().unwrap()).id);
}
```

Results in `error: cost_1 does not live long enough`

With the additional info that "borrowed value dropped before borrower".

So I attempt to add explicit lifetime annotations.

```
#[test]
fn node_cost_dequeue() {
    let mut queue: BinaryHeap<&'a NodeCost> = BinaryHeap::new();
    let cost_1: NodeCost<'a> = NodeCost::new(1, 50, 0);
    let cost_2: NodeCost<'a> = NodeCost::new(2, 30, 0);
    let cost_3: NodeCost<'a> = NodeCost::new(3, 80, 0);
    queue.push(&cost_1);
    queue.push(&cost_2);
    queue.push(&cost_3);
    assert_eq!(2, (*queue.pop().unwrap()).id);
}
```

This results in `use of undeclared lifetime name 'a`.

So, I attempt to declare it on the function

```
fn node_cost_dequeue<'a>() -> () {
```

But this results in `error: functions used as tests must have signature fn() -> ()`

Am I on the right track? How do I declare this lifetime?

Comment: You can find a somewhat similar case (though with a hidden leak due to the same lifetime of both affected objects) in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39827244/1870153).

Comment: See also [How to initialize a variable with a lifetime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108689/how-to-initialize-a-variable-with-a-lifetime) => you cannot, a lifetime *annotation* does not enforce a lifetime, it merely documents it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this is telling you is..

Everything is dropped in reverse order.. `cost_1` will be dropped before `queue`.. because its declared after `queue`. So `queue` has a reference to `cost_1` and because the values are now being dropped at the end of the method `queue` now has a reference to... nothing? `cost_1` has been dropped while `queue` is still "alive" - even though its about to be dropped as well.

To be clear, the sequence of events matters because the `BinaryHeap` instance is storing *references*. It does not own its contents.

The sequence of events will be:

- Declare a `BinaryHeap` instance that stores *references*.
- Declare `cost_1`, `cost_2` and `cost_3`, whose *references* will be inserted into the `BinaryHeap`.
- Add references into `BinaryHeap`.
- Perform assertion.
- Drop `cost_3`.
- Drop `cost_2`.
- Drop `cost_1`.
- **What do the `BinaryHeap` references point to now? The items are dropped.**
- Drop `BinaryHeap`.

The bolded item in the above list is what the compiler is protecting you from. Potentially invalid pointers.

The easy fix.. is to reverse the declaration order such that any references to `cost_1` outlive `queue`:

```
let cost_1: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(1, 50, 0);
let cost_2: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(2, 30, 0);
let cost_3: NodeCost = NodeCost::new(3, 80, 0);
let mut queue: BinaryHeap<&NodeCost> = BinaryHeap::new();
```

Here is a working [example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6782814780e3f22c0891ed221cede677&version=stable&backtrace=0)

The order of events will now be:

- Declare `cost_1`, `cost_2` and `cost_3`, whose *references* will be inserted into the `BinaryHeap`.
- Declare a `BinaryHeap` instance that stores *references*.
- Add references into `BinaryHeap`.
- Perform assertion.
- **Drop `BinaryHeap`.** The references can go away because the items they reference are still alive.
- Drop `cost_3`.
- Drop `cost_2`.
- Drop `cost_1`.