# How can I create 100 distinct labels with type &'static str?

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a graph using `RefCell` and `Rc`. I want to create 100 nodes in a loop with string labels. This is the graph representation:

```
struct Node {
    datum: &'static str,
    edges: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(datum: &'static str) -> Rc<RefCell<Node>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
            datum: datum,
            edges: Vec::new(),
        }))
    }
}
```

This is the loop I am writing to create nodes:

```
for i in 0..100 {
    let a = Node::new(concat!("A", i));
    let b = Node::new(concat!("A", i + 1));
    {
        let mut mut_root = a.borrow_mut();
        mut_root.edges.push(b.clone());
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
error: expected a literal
  --> src/main.rs:17:40
   |
17 |         let a = Node::new(concat!("A", i));
   |                                        ^

error: expected a literal
  --> src/main.rs:18:40
   |
18 |         let b = Node::new(concat!("A", i + 1));
   |                                        ^^^^^
```

Comment: See also [How to create a static string at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32956050/155423)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot.

Lifetimes are descriptive, not prescriptive: you can't create a string and say "this data has the `'static` lifetime." Rust makes you write lifetime annotations like `'static` so that the compiler can check your work. In the case of building a string in a runtime loop, you can't safely call it `'static` because it's not. (See also [How to initialize a variable with a lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108689/how-to-initialize-a-variable-with-a-lifetime))

But that doesn't mean you don't have any options.

#### Avoiding lifetimes altogether

Possibly what you're looking for is just to avoid annotating `Node` with a lifetime parameter, like `Node<'a>`. In which case, just use `String` instead:

```
struct Node {
    datum: String,
    edges: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
}
```

This is idiomatic and most likely the best option. If you're sure you will never need `String`'s methods after creating it, and you don't want to store its capacity, you can call [`String::into_boxed_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_boxed_str) to make it a `Box<str>` instead. This is the same storage-wise as `&'static str`, but the heap storage for the `str` will be reclaimed when the `Node` is dropped.

You could even use `Rc<str>`, which is also the same storage as `&'static str` but cheaper to clone than a `Box`.

#### Making non-static data `'static` by leaking

If you really *want* to, you can "fake" a `&'static str` by making a `Box<str>` and leaking it -- i.e. discarding the knowledge that it's a `Box` so that its backing memory will *never* be reclaimed. Since Rust 1.26, you can use [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak); I'll make a helper function to create the labels:

```
fn label(i: u32) -> &'static str {
    let s = format!("A{}", i);
    Box::leak(s.into_boxed_str())
}
for i in 0..100 {
    let a = Node::new(label(i));
    let b = Node::new(label(i+1));
    // ...
}
```

The main thing this gives you is that `&` references are `Copy`. But `Node` isn't `Copy` anyway, so why not just use `Box`?

#### Generating labels at or before compile time

If you need a string that's *actually* `'static`, it has to be there at compile time. As far as I know, `macro_rules` macros aren't powerful enough to do this, but you can always generate code. Here's one possibility:

```
// This part can be generated by a build script, or in your editor:
static LABELS: [&'static str; 100] = [
    "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "A10", "A11", "A12", "A13", "A14",
    "A15", "A16", "A17", "A18", "A19", "A20", "A21", "A22", "A23", "A24", "A25", "A26", "A27",
    "A28", "A29", "A30", "A31", "A32", "A33", "A34", "A35", "A36", "A37", "A38", "A39", "A40",
    "A41", "A42", "A43", "A44", "A45", "A46", "A47", "A48", "A49", "A50", "A51", "A52", "A53",
    "A54", "A55", "A56", "A57", "A58", "A59", "A60", "A61", "A62", "A63", "A64", "A65", "A66",
    "A67", "A68", "A69", "A70", "A71", "A72", "A73", "A74", "A75", "A76", "A77", "A78", "A79",
    "A80", "A81", "A82", "A83", "A84", "A85", "A86", "A87", "A88", "A89", "A90", "A91", "A92",
    "A93", "A94", "A95", "A96", "A97", "A98", "A99", "A100",
];
for i in 0..100 {
    let a = Node::new(LABELS[i]);
    // ...
}
```

This might not seem like the most elegant solution, but it has several advantages over the above suggestions. The strings don't have to be allocated, so they're as cheap as possible. The code size is smaller. The resulting code is easier for the compiler to optimize. It's easy to generate `LABELS` with an editor macro or a one-liner in your scripting language of choice. It's also trivial to check, because it's just a list of increasing integers. The biggest reason why you would want to avoid code generation is if 100 is a number that may change and you don't want to edit multiple locations in the code when that happens. In that case runtime generation (using one of the ideas above) is probably your best bet.